# Python mod_wsgi write to custom log file instead of apache error_log

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I have a Python application which is deployed in production with Apache and mod_wsgi.
In my application, I have setup logging as follows:

`config` file:

```
log_file = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/app.log"
log_level = logging.DEBUG
```

`__init__.py` file:

```
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(config.log_level)

log_format = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] [%(name)s] %(message)s")

file_handler = logging.FileHandler(config.log_file)
file_handler.setFormatter(log_format)

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(log_format)

root_logger.addHandler(file_handler)
root_logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
```

This code is executed before the Flask application is created.

All logging that is not an error/exception is correctly logged to this custom file.

However, if an exception is generated while the web server is running, the errors are instead written to Apache's error log instead of the one configured here. How do I configure Python's logging/mod_wsgi/Apache so that everything is written to the log file configured here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your logger to WSGI application loggers, from [flask error handling docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/errorhandling/#logging-to-a-file):

```
if not app.debug:
    import logging
    from themodule import TheHandlerYouWant
    file_handler = TheHandlerYouWant(...)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

Comment: Just to add, the logging configuration I set above also worked in logging errors to the correct files. I found that the solution was to remove the following: `app.debug = True`, and then all specified logging worked as expected.

Comment: Good to know that you have figured out the problems.